# Running BeEF on Parrot VM I'm having issues loading the UI

Tags: linux, firefox, parrot-os

Yestarday I was working on getting beef to work but I was getting constant errors I worked on it from around noon to damn near 3 am I now have 0 errors when running it in the terminal as "beef-xss" and it starts firefox but when the Ui loads it has an issue loading the page and can't connect. Ive tried running it manually from /usr/share/beef-xss ./beef -x -a and I get a set of errors that in the end tell me to run bundle install which Ive done numerous times.

Basically I as far as I can tell beef works as long as I run it as the link 'beef-xss' in root but then has issues when loading the ui

any suggestions?